# Altitude and Yeast

Tags: yeast, stuck-fermentation

I live at 9200 feet I am on my second batch of beer. Both batches did not really chug as I call it.First batch tastes great but no carbonation Second batch yeast rose up but went flat in 1 day just added fishtank aerator. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you please provide more details about the batches as I am pretty sure the altitude is not your problem?

Comment: 1 was IPA 1 brewing now is a stout Followed all directions just doesn't seem like yeast is doing its job. IPA tasted great on bottling day but no carbonation in bottles Stout foam 1st day in bucket then flat

Comment: If it foamed up and went flat then the yeast may be mostly done fermenting. I wouldn't use the aerator at this point (may give oxidation). Check your gravity if you can to see how far along fermentation is.

Comment: Are these all grain/kit/partial mash?
How old was your yeast?
Did you make a starter?

Comment: Best Brewers Kit Just followed their instructions Really have no idea how old yeast is. Will the gravity read some where between the beginning and final?

Answer (score 1):

At that elevation you're only about 4 psi lower than sea level.

While it would seem wort wouldn't hold oxygen as well for the yeast at that elevation I think it's negligible.

You can always add more oxygen if the yeast seems slugish, but I would stop once you know alcohol is present.

Sounds more like the yeast is stressed from poor nutients, health, or pitch volume.

Edit: let me start again, **gratz on your first brews**
What you're seeing can be normal fermentation, the foam (krausen) will always fall back in. Your beers Carbonation doesn't happen at this point. Carbonation is achieved by adding a priming sugar when bottling, or by force if kegging. Some kits may have a single vessel for fermenting and serving where the fermentor is sealed like a keg when fermentation nears the end.

Comment: How does yeast get stressed? TY

Comment: @GMan low cell count, low nutrients, high abv, wrong temperatures, low oxygen, all these can make it hard on the yeast.

Comment: Can you add more yeast when you bottle or will that effect the taste?

Comment: @GMan you can and is common to make sure each has sufficient yeast. Drop of trub, or just a few granules of dry does the trick.